# Вывести в датафрейм проценты от столбца

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть df с df['Key'],df['Score'] - где Score это кол-во встречающихся Key. Нужно в новом датафрейме узнать сколько значений в процентах присуще каждому Key.

```
df
Key     Score
0       9.0
1       9.0
2       0.0
3       6.0
4       9.0
5       6.0
6       3.0
7       9.0
8       9.0
9       7.0
```

Узнаем сколько здесь строк - в нашем случае будет 10
`a = df_result.shape[0]`
Теперь нужно узнать какое кол-во значений в этих 10 ти строках наибольшее кол-во. Сейчас мы знаем что Девяток (9.0) здесь пять штук, от 10ти это 50%. Цифр 6 здесь две, это 20%.

Хочу получить новый df, в котором будет так:

```
Key     %
0       10
1       0
2       0
3       10
4       0
5       0
6       20
7       10
8       0
9       50
```

Тоесть мы каждому ключю прописали сколько раз он встречается в df['Score']

Comment: можете пояснить как вы получили такой результат?? Key: 9 - имеет Score: 7.0, который встречается всего один раз. Почему у вас для Key: 9 - результат 50%??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [88]: df["Score"].value_counts().div(len(df)).mul(100)
Out[88]: 
9.0    50.0
6.0    20.0
7.0    10.0
3.0    10.0
0.0    10.0
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Все верно, а можете пояснить почему получается (9.0    = 4.716981)
(6.0    = 1.886792)
(7.0    = 0.943396)
(3.0   =  0.943396)
(0.0   =  0.943396) вот такие значения. Тоесть неполные проценты и еще и не процентами - что мне исправить? (взял в скобки - это то же самое что 9.0 это 50.0 процентов)

Comment: @ЛеонидВ, у вас такие результаты получаются для приведенного в вопросе примера данных??

Comment: res = df_result["Score"].value_counts().div(len(df)).mul(100) - вот так. Без res точно также выходит

Comment: хотя я могу вместо 100 написать 1000. Но все равно хочется узнать почему не целые числа выходят

Comment: я умножаю на 100, чтобы получить проценты вместо фактора, который имеет область значений `[0, 1]`. Чтобы получить целые значения процентов - их можно округлить: `df["Score"].value_counts().div(len(df)).mul(100).round().astype("int8")`

Comment: @ЛеонидВ, я понял что у вас происходит: `df_result["Score"].value_counts().div(len(df)).mul(100)` - делить нужно на длину `df_result`, а не на длину `df` ;) Т.е. : `df_result["Score"].value_counts().div(len(df_result)).mul(100)`